# .NET MVC4, Entity, Search

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 project using EF. I have set up my schema so that all searchable items have have a Table that relates them to a "Tags" table. I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do a full search across all table related to this "Tags" table. In addition I will want to do a search across the titles/names of the item in question. Not sure what is the best way to go about this.

I drew a little diagram of this schema:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code would look like:

```
var tagged = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductTag.Any(pt => pt.Tag.Name.Contains("Search")));
```

But it would all depend on how your model is setup.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of "Find" command where it will search for any entry whose "name" contains a string?

Comment: You can just use the .NET method of `string.Contains`. I edited my answer above.

Comment: I will probably end up doing this. I hope its fast enough though. Thanks for your help.